# How do I add the link from the zip code warning message using an i18n CSV file?

Tags: magento2.4

[image]

How do I add the link from the zip code warning message in magento 2 using an i18n CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying is not possible because https://drops.meetanshi.com/rwGdEr
data-bind property is with text thats why it consider as text

if you change this html file and set data-bind="html: element.warn" than it work properly

Comment: how to Override this file?

Comment: https://meetanshi.com/blog/override-js-file-in-magento-2/ follow this block to override js file, and in js you need to pass html file path

Comment: Not working. please provide more details